# How to get total number of users per city by using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (User table and City Table)

```
User Table:
Column: Userid, username, package, cityid

City Table:
Column: CityID, Cityname etc
```

I want to display total number of users  per city. There is one to many relation in both tables. City table can have multiple users.

Expected output

```
Cityname   Number of users
London     1000
Newyork    2000
California 2500
```

Comment: is any reference between User and City table

Comment: Yes there should be any mapping between these both tables

Comment: user belong to city  and city has many users

Comment: is there any reference between both table?

Comment: Means User table has City ID or City table has User id?

Comment: is there any primary and foreign key?

Comment: I'm just looking for an optimized method to display the results

Comment: u can use `join` if there is any reference in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join both tables in order to be able to access the data in both, at the same time.

```
SELECT t2.cityName
    ,count(t1.cityId) AS Users_from_city
FROM [User] t1
INNER JOIN city t2 ON t1.cityId = t2.cityId
GROUP BY t2.cityName
```

Then, by using a `COUNT()`, which is an aggregated function, you determine the number of users from each city.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
select t2.[cityName] as [City],
count(t1.[cityId]) as [Total Number of users]
from [User] t1
join [city] t2
on t1.[cityId] = t2.[cityId];
```

[Read about JOIN here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want all users in the city id 1:

```
 select city.city_id,user.* 
    from city,user 
   where user.city_id=city.city_id 
     and city.city_id=1;
```

Check it and if needed modify it according to your requirement.